# Displaying another ListView when a row element of a ListView is clicked

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView in which each row has a associated set of items. So when a row of first ListView is clicked, items associated with this row should rearranges into a ListView and this ListView should take the place of first ListView, i.e. the first ListView should be replaced by second listView.

Please suggest me a good way to do this?

Also suggest me a solution if there are more than one level, i.e. second listview also has a associated items and they should also rearranges itself into listView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two ListFragment for First and Second List.
Attached the First fragment list to the activity. When an item(row) is clicked , replace the first fragment with second one.

Now you will see the second attached fragment list.

Comment: No, I don't want to use fragments because I am making widget and I want to avoid fragments in it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) ?

For deeper levels, you should adopt a different strategy. Among them :

- each list view should be displayed in its own activity (phone) / fragment (tablet) with some scrolling/page viewing for even deeper levels.
- you could use a breadcrumb like in [OI FileManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager&hl=fr)

Comment: No, I don't think ExpandableListView will work. I need to **replace** the first listview with the child ListView

Answer (score 0):

So Basically you wanted a ListView in which if you clicked On the Item of a ListView previous listView should be replaced with newer one?

This is possible by FrameLayout and Fragments. 
read docs here
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

ASSUMING YOU HAVE CUSTOM LISTVIEW ADAPTER
now suppose you have `listView` say `lv`;

firstsetup Listner Method

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View parent, int position,long id) 

     {

    displayAnotherListView(position);

     }  
  });
```

Now you need to create this Method called `displayAnotherListView(int position)`

You can do that By

```
private void displaynAotherListView(int position) {

        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (position)
        {
        case 0:
            {
                fragment=new NewListFragments();
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            {
                fragment=new OtherFragment();
            }
        default:
                   {
                            break;
                    }

                    if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

              // Details about your fragments list here
            } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }


   }
```

Again You need to know about fragments.
I would rather suggest you to use activities for juming from one listview to another.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer but I am making widget and I want to avoid fragments in it. Can you suggest some other method

Comment: So Basically You can used activities instead of fragments. you should post some code that would make whole idea clear and we can help you little further

Comment: I haven't written any code yet and exploring the ways to do this.So I want to know when I click a row in ListView how to replace the first view(ListView) to another view(ListView) or there could be another way also, We can replace data of first ListView with other data and add/remove rows from first ListView to change to second ListView

Comment: You can replace data of that PARTICULAR LIST ROW with another data that's for sure. And It is simple enough just try a little code your self then post we will help you further